# Does dvc checkout pulls the data or just checkouts .dvc files?

Tags: dvc

I am testing data tracking via dvc (data version control) . I went through the example at dvc.org and added the data. and added the files generated to git as well. now , after I do run

```
git checkout
```

do I run dvc pull or dvc checkout. what do these command do behind the scenes?

```
project
  .dvc
  train.py
  data
    abc.csv
  data.dvc
```

I have initialized a git repository , installed and initialized dvc and added some data with command below

```
dvc add data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dvc pull`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/pull) command is the same as [`dvc fetch`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/fetch) + [`dvc checkout`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/checkout).

`dvc fetch` is downloading data from the remote storage (can be S3, Google Cloud, etc) into DVC cache, while `checkout` then "instantiates" those file in the workspace.

Not a perfect comparison, but roughly you can compare `dvc pull` with `git pull`, `dvc fetch` with `git fetch`, and `dvc checkout` with `git checkout`- they serve similar purpose but for large files or directories that you want to save not in Git directly, but on the cloud, SSH, NAS server, etc.

Btw, besides `dvc add` you need to run `dvc push` to save your data, so that your team (or you on a different) machine could run `dvc pull` later.

Comment: What happens when I run dvc checkout without running dvc fetch?